# Bind silverlight combobox to the result of another combobox

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, xaml

I want to do something like this:

```
<combobox x:Name="cboCustomers" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data.Customers}"/>
<combobox x:Name="cboInvoices"ItemsSource="{cboCustomers.SelectedItem.Invoices}"/>
```

Anyone know of a way to do something like this in Silverlight 3?  I am sure there is some information about it out there, but I am having bad luck with Google in forming the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify `ElementName` on the second binding:

```
<combobox x:Name="cboCustomers" ItemsSource="{Binding Data.Customers}"/>
<combobox x:Name="cboInvoices"ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Invoices, ElementName=cboCustomers}"/>
```

If you also want the second combobox to be disabled until something has been selected in the first combobox you can bind the `IsEnabled` property of the second combobox to the `SelectedItem` property of the first combobox through a converter.

Add this class to your project:

```
public class NullToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter {

  public Object Convert(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    if (targetType == typeof(Boolean))
      return value != null;
    throw new NotSupportedException("Value converter can only convert to Boolean type.");
  }

  public Object ConvertBack(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    throw new NotSupportedException("Value converter cannot convert back.");
  }

}
```

Add an instance of this class to the resource dictionary of your user control (`local` is the namespace tag for the namespace of the converter):

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <local:NullToBooleanConverter x:Key="NullToBooleanConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then you can add this to the second combobox:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=cboCustomers, Converter={StaticResource NullToBooleanConverter}}"
```

Answer (score 3):

You'd be looking at a Cascading Combobox

http://weblogs.asp.net/manishdalal/archive/2008/10/22/cascading-combobox.aspx